# European culture codes

Tags: vb.net

I have a brief question about the use of culture codes in Visual Basic. What I have is a dropdown menu where someone can select what currency they use in their country. All is great until I have to decide what to do about the Euro lol! My thinking is simply to use the current culture that is in their computer, assuming they use Euros. My question: if I use a culture code for any nation in the EU that uses Euros (example: Netherlands) within the application (for currency appearance purposes), would this work as a generic code to cover any country that uses the Euro? I had to refer to a wiki page to tell me which countries didn't use the Euro so I included their specific currencies. The code also saves the desired culture setting when the program starts up again, rather than defaulting to the one on the computer. The code does work. I'm just wondering if there's a better way because I don't know if a user's current culture is going to be one that uses Euros unless I test it against a list of 17 countries.) Here's a sample of my code to show you what I'm talking about:

```
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "EURO (€)" Then
        Me.CurrencyDataSet.CURR(0).CURRTYPE = "EUR"
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL")
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL")
    End If
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "FRANC (Fr)" Then
        Me.CurrencyDataSet.CURR(0).CURRTYPE = "FR"
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR")
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR")
    End If
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "POUND (£)" Then
        Me.CurrencyDataSet.CURR(0).CURRTYPE = "GBP"
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB")
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB")
    End If
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "ZLOTY (zl)" Then
        Me.CurrencyDataSet.CURR(0).CURRTYPE = "ZL"
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pl-PL")
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pl-PL")
    End If
```

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Are you selecting a culture or a currency?

Comment: Hi Magnus, basically trying to select a "generic" code that would display a Euro currency value safely for the 17 countries that use that currency. I've decided to use Netherlands for now but not sure if there are implications from doing this. I suspect the changes in current culture made in the application (simply to display currency) do not persist when the user exits?